# Обработка массива PHP

Tags: массивы, php, html

Есть табличка на html из 3х колонок, в первой колонке текст, во второй чекбокс и в третьей текстовое поле. Количество строк заранее не известно.

Теперь сам вопрос: как с помощью php все это дело занести в базу mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот такую конструкцию.
Это когда не известно сколько будет инпутов.
Это только конструкция. В цикл нужно вставить запросы в базу, которые добавляют в нее полученные данные.

```
<?php

for( $k=0; $k<count( $_POST[ 'item_name' ] ); $k++ )
{
    print $_POST[ 'item_name' ][ $k ];
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="item_name[]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="item_name[]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="item_name[]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. задать имя каждому из текстбоксов ( текстовое поле )
2. все текстбоксы должны быть в форме
3. убедиться что есть б.д. и таблица, в которую нужно добавлять
4. соедениться с базой
5. добавить данные с помощью команд INSERT INTO (name_textbox) values ($peremennaya1,$peremennaya2...)

( п.5 - ответ на вопрос )

Вам нужно хоть чуть чуть поучить теорию (хэлп) с пунктами 3-5 и все получиться

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю хранить данные виде JSON строки. У меня уже в 2 проектах успешно работает. Полная динамичность, может быть неизвестно даже какие поля будут. Но есть минусы: с базы не сможете выбирать с помощью WHERE aaa="bbb" и подобные.

Comment: А можно получить пример кода как это реализовать?